# Expo React Native String to BigInt

Tags: reactjs, react-native, type-conversion, expo

I am trying to get unique ID for my device and I get is successfully with `Constants.deviceId`. However, I need it in 8 bytes (BigInt type). Is it possible somehow?

Device ID in string looks like this: "AAAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEEFFFFGGGG"

Is it better to use another approach and just generate a random 8 byte number and use it as unique ID for the device?

Answer (score 0):

Can you encode it as base64?

`yarn add Base64`.

```
import Base64 from 'Base64';
 
const encoded = Base64.btoa('AAAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEEFFFFGGGG');
const decoded = Base64.atob(encoded);

// Should return QUFBQUFBQUEtQkJCQi1DQ0NDLUREREQtRUVFRUZGRkZHR0dH
```

[npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/Base64).
[Blog with more info](https://blog.lysender.com/2019/05/using-base64-encode-decode-in-a-react-native-expo-app/)

Comment: What about using the imei? This will still return it as a string, but it will be all numbers [react-native-imei](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-imei) This won't work on Apple, only Android.

Comment: its good, but still, I need it both on iOS and Android :(

Comment: Can you clarify why it has to be a number?

Comment: it is accepted by the database in this format to optimise performance (the number will be used a search attribute)